# Date formatting for SOQL String - unexpected output

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, date, formatting

I have '273' added as a day with the following line:

```
DateTime.newInstance(dStart.year(), dstart.month(), dstart.day()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

so the output looks like '273-09-2019' -  what gives?

I am trying to add a date to a SOQL string and a Date type returns '30-09-2019 00:00:00'. A few suggestions were to convert Date to DateTime and then apply to format. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be small `dd` aka `dd-MM-YYYY`

```
Date dStart = System.today();    

System.debug(DateTime.newInstance(dStart.year(), dstart.month(), dstart.day()).format('dd-MM-YYYY')); //13-11-2019
```

Format method follows [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and according to it

Small d means date and Caps D means day of the year

Comment: As an addendum to this answer, Apex's date formatting method(s) accept format strings that adhere to [Java's SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). `DD` = day of the year (0 to 365 or 366), `dd` = day of the month (with leading 0).

Comment: Thanks @DerekF :)

Comment: Cheers fellas! I can't believe how much time I wasted on this.